# Can't knit RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, readxl

When I'm knitting my r markdown document it all runs smoothly until 1 chunk near the end where I get the error in the render tab (near where the console is):

[error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ44C.png)

I'll write down what the code says just in case the image doesn't load:

```
Quitting from lines 1321-1372 (narrative_analysis2.Rmd)

Error in app$vspace(new_style$`margin-top` %||% 0) :

    attempt to apply non-function

  Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> .transformer -> clii__container_start

  Execution halted
```

Lines 1321 - 1372 are in a specific chunk where no errors come up when I run that specific chunk. I uploaded my excel data through readxl package. The chunk before and the chunk after all run smoothly. I don't know what is the issue. narrative_analysis2 is the name I saved the markdown as.

I have reinstalled knitr, readr, readxl, cli and restarted the session and nothing has worked. I don't understand why it won't knit.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: 50 lines is a long chunk. I'd suggest breaking it into smaller pieces to narrow down the problem. When it's down to a small size chunk causing the problem, edit your question to include the code.

Comment: Hi, you were right. I had to split up the chunks and only then did the errors come through which I managed to solve. I didn't realise that too long chunks would cause an issue like this.

Comment: Too long chunks aren't an issue in themselves that I'm aware of. But the first step of debugging anything is to isolate and identify the problem, and 50 lines is the opposite of isolated.